# Non matching word from file1 to file2

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have two files - file1 & file2.
file1 contains (only words) says-

```
ABC
YUI
GHJ
I8O
```

..................

file2 contains many para.

```
dfghjo ABC kll njjgg bla bla 
GHJ njhjckhv chasjvackvh ..
ihbjhi hbhibb jh jbiibi
```

...................

I am using below command to get the matching lines which contains word from file1 in file2

```
 grep -Ff file1 file2
(Gives output of lines where words of file1 found in file2)
```

I also need the words which doesn't match/found in file 2 and unable to find Un-matching word.

Can anyone help in getting below output

```
YUI
I8O
```

i am looking one liner command (via grep,awk,sed), as i am using pssh command and can't use while,for loop

Comment: To get the matching lines, please try:
`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} a[$0]' file1 file2`

Answer (score 1):

You can print only the matched parts with `-o`.

```
$ grep -oFf file1 file2
ABC
GHJ
```

Use that output as a list of patterns for a search in file1. Process substitution `<(cmd)` simulates a file containing the output of `cmd`. With `-v` you can print lines that did not match. If file1 contains two lines such that one line is a substring of another line you may want to add `-x` (only match whole lines)   to prevent false positives.

```
$ grep -vxFf <(grep -oFf file1 file2) file1
YUI
I8O
```

Comment: you may want to add `-w` there to eliminate substring matches.

Comment: @karakfa good point, although I would use `-x`. In general, patterns could contain non-word characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl - both matched/non-matched in same one-liner

```
$ cat sinw.txt
ABC
YUI
GHJ
I8O

$ cat sin_in.txt
dfghjo ABC kll njjgg bla bla
GHJ njhjckhv chasjvackvh ..
ihbjhi hbhibb jh jbiibi

$ perl -lne '
    BEGIN { %x=map{chomp;$_=>1} qx(cat sinw.txt); $w="\\b".join("\|",keys %x)."\\b"} 
    print "$&" and delete($x{$&}) if /$w/ ; 
    END { print "\nnon-matched\n".join("\n", keys %x) } 
' sin_in.txt

ABC
GHJ

non-matched
I8O
YUI

$
```

Getting only the non-matched

```
$ perl -lne ' 
    BEGIN { 
        %x = map { chomp; $_=>1 } qx(cat sinw.txt); 
        $w = "\\b" . join("\|",keys %x) . "\\b" 
    } 
    delete($x{$&}) if /$w/;
    END { print "\nnon-matched\n".join("\n", keys %x) } 
' sin_in.txt

non-matched
I8O
YUI

$
```

Note that even a single use of [$& variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$&) used to be very expensive for the whole program, in Perl versions [prior to 5.20](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues).

Comment: @zdim.. have a look at 54712459.. kvantour has done bench-marking for different answers and Perl came close ( 13 secs vs 9 Secs excl bio-awk answer ) .. Im not good at tuning.. give a try!!

Comment: @zdim.. i just did now..again thank you.. catch you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "words" in file1 are in more than 1 line :

```
  while read line 
  do 
    for word in $line  
    do 
       if ! grep -q $word file2
         then echo $word not found 
       fi 
    done 
  done < file1
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am looking one liner command (via grep,awk,sed), as i am using pssh command and can't use while,for loop

Comment: @Sin15 this can be run as a one liner too : `while read line; do for word in $line ; do if ! grep -q $word file2; then echo $word not found; fi; done; done < file1`

Answer (score 0):

For *Un-matching words*, here's one GNU `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)' RS='[ \n]' file2 file1
YUI
I8O
```

Or `!($0 in a)`, it's the same. Since I set `RS='[ \n]'`, every space as *line* separator too.

And note that I read file2 first, and then file1.

If file2 could be empty, you should change `NR==FNR` to different file checking methods, like `ARGIND==1` for GNU awk, or `FILENAME=="file2"`, or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` etc.

Same mechanism for *only the matched one* too:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' RS='[ \n]' file2 file1
ABC
GHJ
```